# Does IOS delete WebSQL databases when low on storage capacity?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using WebSQL databases to store my data in my ionic app, but I've read that if you use LocalStorage the data might be lost on IOS if the smartphone is low on storage capacity. So I wondered if the same is apparent for the WebSQL?

Comment: Did you ever find out if WebSQL databases can be deleted by iOS at all? I am experiencing something similar and any advice or hunches you may have would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to use WebSQL databases as it is deprecated. An excerpt from Web clearly states the following:

> Since November 18, 2010, the W3C announced that Web SQL database is a deprecated specification. This is a recommendation for web developers to no longer use the technology as effectively, the spec will receive no new updates and browser vendors aren't encouraged to support this technology. The new alternative is IndexedDB which is already available on Chrome 12+, Firefox 5+ and in IE 10+ as well.

As far as i know incase of Cordova, its better to use [SQLite storage plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) for storing data.